# Creating an Arc-style menu in a Desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menu

How can we create an Arc menu in a WinForms desktop application? The best example I can show you to explain what I mean is with this picture:

[image]

The expected behaviour of this menu will be:
 - Right-clicking brings up the menu
   - Hovering over the menu items highlights them
   - Clicking a menu item performs an action and closes the menu.

It's incredibly hard to do any research on this, since searching for things like `arc menu`, `arc menu winforms`, `arc menu windows forms` doesn't display any related results. I'm even surprised that searching for `arc menu` doesn't show *anything at all* related to an arc menu.

Comment: maybe the correct keyword is `circle menu`?

Comment: Thanks, @KingKing. I just searched for Circle menu and it brought up a lot of similar menus. All of them were full circles, though I'm sure I could manage to make it an arc :)

Comment: I've found the more exact keyword that is `Radial Menu`.

Comment: The only available resources seem to be from 3rd party companies. If anybody knows of anything _other than that_, please do post an answer. Documentation, custom jobs, articles, even dirty hacks would be appreciated. Anything that might help give me a rough idea of how these things are made.

Comment: winforms doesn't support that. If you want something like that you will have to create it yourself using a horrible amount of procedural code and something called "owner draw". Only to find out it flickers constantly due to lack of hardware acceleration.

Comment: If you need to customize the look and feel of your application, I strongly suggest WPF.